# Using board-to-board pins and crimp receptacles to attach a non-board receptacle to a board

Tags: soldering, pcb-assembly

I imagine this is a bit of a stretch, but I'm working through some iterations of a cable harness for a 3D printer. I've considered that a custom PCB may be in order (still on the fence there), but the actual connectors I'm using right now really fit the bill (the TE1981921-1 here: https://www.te.com/usa-en/product-1981921-1.html).  I'm really intent on that due to the pin density at the given wire gauge and haven't found anything designed for boards that's close.

All that said, there isn't a wire-to-board option.  I briefly toyed with the idea of crimping the receptacles to board-to-board pins, adding a touch of solder, then soldering THOSE to the board, but I can't tell if this is "Hillbilly electronics" or if it's a feasible idea.  Is there a reason to avoid this method?  Obviously proper spacers would need to be involved, both between the jack case and board and the board and cut-through to prevent the board from cracking when you plug it in.  But are there any other reasons this would be bad?  The actual power draw should be fairly low - though it's rated highly and I considered pushing my hot end power through that connection (up to 24V @ 40W), though would be happy to also run a cable and surface mount some XT30s for power if there's a resistance or possible desolder issue with the power line.

Anyway, I'm new to DIY electronics, so thought it'd be best just to ask.  Thanks!

Comment: It's a PITA to take apart should you ever need to. Why would you crimp then solder? That's a waste of time. If you are going to solder just solder directly.

Comment: Well, yeah, that's fair.  In this case I wouldn't have need to take it apart - just as with a normal wire-to-board receptacle, it would remain resident permanently.

Comment: https://www.molex.com/molex/products/datasheet.jsp?part=active/5054483671_PCB_HEADERS.xml

Comment: @ScottSeidman - those are nice, and I tend to like Molex, but I'm not confident in my ability to mount SMT components, especially components that will receive some amount of wear.  I'll definitely consider it, though.  Thank you!